# Nhibernate ignoring unsaved-value with Guid (SQL Server CE)

Tags: nhibernate, guid

This is my mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="DomainModel" namespace="DomainModel">
  <class name="Cliente" table="Clientes">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" type="guid" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Nombre" column="Nombre" not-null="true" type="string" length="50"  />
    <property name="Direccion" column="Direccion" not-null="false" type="string" length="75"  />
    <property name="Telefono" column="Telefono" not-null="false" type="string" length="15"  />
    <property name="Email" column="Email" not-null="false" type="string" length="50"  />
    <property name="FechaAlta" column="FAlta" not-null="true" type="DateTime"  />
    <list name="Pedidos" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="Cliente"/>
      <index column="FechaEntrada"/>
      <one-to-many class="Pedido"/>
    </list>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to insert a new "Cliente" (Customer) into the database, NHibernate generates instead an UPDATE command, looking to update the customer with ID 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. As it doesn't exist, I naturally get the exception:

InnerException: NHibernate.StaleStateException
       Message="Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1"

I'm guessing this has to be a noob NHibernate error, but I've been checking my mapping with other guid example mappings on the web and I don't see my mistake.

Thanks!

PS.- As requested, this is the code I use to do the insertion:

```
// METHOD 1
//BusinessTransaction bt = new BusinessTransaction(sesion);
//bt.Attach(cliente);
//bt.Commit();
//bt.Close();

// METHOD 2
ITransaction trans = sesion.BeginTransaction();
sesion.SaveOrUpdate(cliente);
trans.Commit();
sesion.Flush();
```

*sesion* is an ISession object created with the BuildSessionFactory method of NHibernate Configuration. *Method 1* provokes the error described, an UPDATE when it should be doing an INSERT, while *Method 2* works, however (I'm an idiot and was looking a the wrong database file).

PPS.- For the sake of testing I've changed the guid fields for auto-incremented int identity fields, but my problems are the same.

PPPS.- Just in case, this are the contents of my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=Pedidos.sdf</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
      <mapping assembly="PedidosDomainModel" />
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: try change `type="guid"` to `type="System.Guid"`

Comment: Show us the code you use to insert your entity. I bet the problem is there

Comment: Everything is working now, even Guids. Using "Method 2" of my code has done the trick, however I'd thank an answer explaining why...

Comment: Well, Method 2 is the correct way to detect if an object is transient or persistent then save it to the database. I'm sorry but I don't know the "BusinessTransaction" object. Where does it come from ?

Comment: BusinessTransaction turns to be a domain layer object from a custom framework on my job, sorry about that. I thought it was part of NHibernate. I consider this question closed. Thanks mCasamento and Firo.

Comment: maybe BusinessTransaction uses `sesion.Update();` inside, which forces NH to update it

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution: Map the Id (that's how I map it in Fluent, you will sort out an equivalent in XML mapping)

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

And before saving you can do something like this:

```
if (client.HasEmptyId())
{
    client.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    session.Save(client);
}
else
{
    session.Update(client);
}
```